# ¿Por qué no funciona este código de php?

Tags: php, api

Holaa, estoy intentando hacer que a través de ipqualityscore reciba ciertos parámetros a través de su api, pero sin embargo no funciona por más que intento y da el siguiente error:

> [Mon Dec 20 16:15:18.426147 2021] [php:warn] [pid 7728:tid 1796] [client 127.0.0.1:1121] PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\tusc\trie\assets\php\app.php on line 7, referer: http://127.0.0.1/tusc/trie/load.php

Dejo aquí el code:

```
$ip = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$key = 'censurado';
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
$user_language = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
$host = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$fraud_score = $result['fraud_score'];
// Set the strictness for this query. (0 (least strict) - 3 (most strict))
$strictness = 1;

// You may want to allow public access points like coffee shops, schools, corporations, etc...
$allow_public_access_points = 'true';

// Reduce scoring penalties for mixed quality IP addresses shared by good and bad users.
$lighter_penalties = 'false';

// Create parameters array.
$parameters = array(
    'user_agent' => $user_agent,
    'user_language' => $user_language,
    'strictness' => $strictness,
    'allow_public_access_points' => $allow_public_access_points,
    'lighter_penalties' => $lighter_penalties,
    'fraud_score' => $fraud_score,
    
);

/* User & Transaction Scoring
* Score additional information from a user, order, or transaction for risk analysis
* Please see the documentation and example code to include this feature in your scoring:
* https://www.ipqualityscore.com/documentation/proxy-detection/transaction-scoring
* This feature requires a Premium plan or greater
*/

// Format Parameters
$formatted_parameters = http_build_query($parameters);

// Create API URL
$url = sprintf(
    'https://www.ipqualityscore.com/api/json/ip/%s/%s?%s', 
    $key,
    $ip,
    $formatted_parameters,
);

// Fetch The Result
$timeout = 5;

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

$json = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// Decode the result into an array.
$result = json_decode($json, true);




$mode = $_POST['dust'];
$content_login = '<pre>
                Country: '.$fraud_score.'
</pre>';
```

Comment: Parece que la línea 7 es `$fraud_score = $result['fraud_score'];` y no puedes acceder a `$result` porque no has definido esa variable. Mueve la línea al final, justo debajo de `$result = json_decode($json, true);`

Comment: he probado a hacer eso pero me sale ahora este error: @Triby
[Mon Dec 20 16:56:31.079782 2021] [php:warn] [pid 7728:tid 1784] [client 127.0.0.1:28352] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "fraud_score" in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\tusc\\trie\\assets\\php\\app.php on line 59, referer: http://127.0.0.1/tusc/trie/

Answer (score 0):

tras haber pensado algunas soluciones me he decantado a crear una constante que contenga una función php y a través de AJAX he mandado la solicitud con los datos de esta constante y así he podido obtener el valor real.
Código por si a alguien le sirve:
Index.php

```
const pais = '<?php echo $pais; ?>';
     $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "./assets/php/app.php",
                    data: { pais: pais   }
                }).done(function (msg) {
                    console.log("Los datos que se recibieron: " + msg);
                });
```

app.php:

```
$pais = $_POST['pais'];
```